# need to open modal window after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to open modal window after ajax call success.

JQUERY:

```
$(".vijai").on("click", function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $base ?>/retailer/Suppliersorder/Supplier_OrderPreview",
        type: "post",
        context: document.body,
        async:false,   //NOTE THIS
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        success: function(d) {

                        alert(d);
                        jQuery('#myModal').show();
                 }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success vijai" id='murugan'> 
    <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i> 
    Order Preview
</button>
```

Comment: Does the alert fire?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery dialog module when you mention modal, reference: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You can replace the line that has `jQuery('#myModal').show();` with `jQuery('#myModal').dialog('open');`

*NOTE*: `url: "<?php echo $base ?>/retailer/Suppliersorder/Supplier_OrderPreview"` seems a bit weird, I'm assuming you have this javascript in a php file instead of javascript file.

Comment: Thanks for your response.jQuery('#myModal').modal('show') it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".updateBtn").click(function(){
    var ruleID = this.id;
     $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: '/admins/getRules/'+ ruleID,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#myModal').modal({'show' : true});
            console.log(data);
        } 
      });

  });
```